# Circle CI: Cannot find module ‘../../Themes’ from ‘RoundButton.js’. Working OK locally

Tags: react-native, jestjs, circleci

I just started adding tests in this project and decided to add Circle CI.
It is working great so far, including the tests. But when I run it in CircleCI, it fails.

circleci.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          - v1-dependencies-
      - run: yarn install
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run: yarn test
```

Test output:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
yarn test
yarn run v1.3.2
$ jest --coverage
 FAIL  __tests__/Components/Shared/RoundButton.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '../../Themes' from 'RoundButton.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/Shared/RoundButton.js:12:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.514s
Ran all test suites.
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Exited with code 1
```

Paths:

```
./__tests__/Components/Shared/RoundButton.js
./src/Components/Shared/RoundButton.js
./src/Themes
```

Versions:

```
"babel-jest": "^22.2.2",
"jest": "^22.4.2",
```

Comment: Does this happen if you run it locally in the same directory?

Comment: I tried over SSH and it happens too. I cloned in a new folder locally and it doesn't happen (but I'm having indenting errors on the snapshots, which I'm checking why atm) @NickMcCurdy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me: it was a case-sensitive issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Locally all tests were passing but then, on circleci I was getting module not found error. I figured out that locally I was importing a component named `Header` (with capital H) but on git, it was named `header`.